# Writing a word in a rhombus/diamond shape in Java

Tags: java, printing, shapes, ascii-art

I have to write a program that asks a word and then prints it in a rhombus/diamond shape, like this:

```
Word: Hello
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
 ello
  llo
   lo
    o
```

I tried something but I really could use some help if someone could, I tried something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rhombus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Word: ");
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        int wordLength = word.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0, i));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printRhombusText("yolobird");
}

public static void printRhombusText(String s) {
    // top part
    for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, i));
    }
    // bottom part
    for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); ++i) {
        // print out the space
        for (int y = i; y > 0; --y) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(s.substring(i));
    }
}
```

output:

```
y
yo
yol
yolo
yolob
yolobi
yolobir
yolobird
 olobird
  lobird
   obird
    bird
     ird
      rd
       d
```

Want to add user input? Here:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Input your text: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        printRhombusText(input);
        scanner.reset();
        System.out.print("You want to do one more? (y/n): ");
    } while (scanner.nextLine().trim().equals("y"));
}
```

output:

```
Input your text: kiet
k
ki
kie
kiet
 iet
  et
   t
    
You want to do one more? (y/n): y
Input your text: ahihi
a
ah
ahi
ahih
ahihi
 hihi
  ihi
   hi
    i
     
You want to do one more? (y/n): n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to output a word in a rhombus shape.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNb8IwDL3zK6yeioDCrnxcdkeTxnHaIbRZY9YmUeLAponf3jmllAI51I3t5/f8chBHMTNW6kPx3TQ27CvMIa@E97AVqOFvBHy6vCdBHI4GC6i5mu7IoS4/PkG40o@75nguBQY42EDyrt7q17BLVn0dNYHiEjdkldQlqXR8q87nQCcDVjjyS9CyZNqjBKELsMZjvEwBM5kNEcFa6Xhw7qTwkTy2V@bEyUJekz3gyzhIowpkFS8wA7Xi33UbJpPhKt34k0KS4K3IJQsrisgQh5CSvahW8R2wpzkwzWLFYQ3IIVLsfj3JOjOBMstuUZpAMjCh4@23j7OXrWE@7H3rb7qYsosTwGfYnaRHGDLsAXJ9sLDvXuXWvRWkslr8RDYcT@Fy59dXV/Znel7KBmrNqVDLe6qHvSudMtlgxnl0@Z6b5h8)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "RhOmBuS";
    int h = str.length();
    // two parts: negative and positive, i.e.
    // upper increasing and lower decreasing
    for (int i = 1 - h; i < h; i++) {
        // white space padding for the positive part
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) System.out.print(" ");
        // negative part: str.substring(0, h + i);
        // positive part: str.substring(i, h);
        String sub = str.substring(Math.max(0, i), Math.min(h, h + i));
        // output the line
        System.out.println(sub);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
R
Rh
RhO
RhOm
RhOmB
RhOmBu
RhOmBuS
 hOmBuS
  OmBuS
   mBuS
    BuS
     uS
      S
```

---

<sup>See also: [Print a rhombus pattern from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249793/16314724)</sup>