# Print a rhombus pattern from user input

Tags: java, shapes, ascii-art

I have a task to ask user for input (user's name) and then to print a rhombus pattern out of it.
For example:
If user's name is Thomas, then the output should be like this:

```
T
Th
Tho
Thom
Thoma
Thomas
 homas
  omas
   mas
    as
     s
```

This is my code so far. I am having trouble with second for loop. I can easily print out lines until "Thomas", but I don't know, how to print whitespace infront so that the end of the word will be on the same place.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordRhombus {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    int enteredNamesLength = name.length();

    for (int i = 0; i <= enteredNamesLength; i++) {
      System.out.println(name.substring(0, (int) i));

      for (int j = 1, k = 1; j <= enteredNamesLength; i++, k++) {
        System.out.println(k * " " + name.substring(j, enteredNamesLength));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there must be one for loop to print the name like what you did, then another for space and inside the same print the substring.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    int enteredNamesLength = name.length();

    for (int i = 0; i <= enteredNamesLength; i++) {
            System.out.println(name.substring(0, (int) i));
    }

    for(int i = 1;i <= enteredNamesLength; i++ ) {
            for(int j = 0;j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(name.substring(i, enteredNamesLength));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to do it in 2 times : `substring` from start to an index, and then print the spaces followed by the end of the world, ans some changes to do :

- no need to cast `i` as int, it's already an `int`
- *first loop* : start index `i` at 1 and not 0, no avoid empty line
- *second loop* : end index for `i` at `enteredNamesLength-1` and not `enteredNamesLength` to avoid also an empty line

---

```
for (int i = 1; i <= enteredNamesLength; i++) {    // start at 1
    System.out.println(name.substring(0, i));      // don't cast
}

for (int i = 1; i < enteredNamesLength; i++) {     // stop at enteredNamesLength-1
    for (int space = 0; space <= i; space++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(name.substring(i, enteredNamesLength));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, you can extract a `print` method which accepts a `start` and `stop`. If the `index` between them, then print character at `index`, otherwise print whitespace.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordRhombus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        int enteredNamesLength = name.length();

        for (int start = 0, stop = 0; start < enteredNamesLength && stop < enteredNamesLength; ) {
            print(start, stop, name);
            if (stop < enteredNamesLength - 1) {
                stop++;
            } else {
                start++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void print(int start, int stop, String name) {
        for (int index = 0; index < name.length(); index++) {
            if (index >= start && index <= stop) {
                System.out.print(name.charAt(index));
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the upper *increasing* part and the lower *decreasing* part in one loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVGxboMwEN3zFScmEAlJ15AunbpElRp1qjoYcOEoMRY@klZVvp2eHUqAeOAw7957945SnMSq1lKV2VfX6TapMIW0EsbAXqCC3wXw6b8bEsTlVGMGR0b9AzWo8vcPEE1ugr7ZnivAhAYewXt9ftk/vR28eMBRESiGuCGqpMqp8IMbul4DnWvQoiGzBSVztj1JECoDXRu0l6H3s27At3LIcg@wAhXz686VMBzP1CtXUmR2tnOBJI0WqTROhAo5qDvrCXGwKdlmE3PZAXKxFocfQ/IY1S1FmmOT74E3StP7DjGs9tYlN21i3KL8zZLXEQLe0yYjzWnItBnlf/Nt0q/31r0XVERH8W3dMFjC9c6/0VlbqXt7DqVbcsupUMmp1Sx3pXw2G2lcFtfnpev@AA)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "RHOMBUS";
    int n = str.length();
    // two parts: negative and positive
    for (int i = 1 - n; i < n; i++) {
        // leading whitespaces for the positive part
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) System.out.print(" ");
        // negative part: str.substring(0, n + i);
        // positive part: str.substring(i, n);
        String sub = str.substring(Math.max(0, i), Math.min(n + i, n));
        // output the line
        System.out.println(sub);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
R
RH
RHO
RHOM
RHOMB
RHOMBU
RHOMBUS
 HOMBUS
  OMBUS
   MBUS
    BUS
     US
      S
```

---

<sup>See also: [Writing a word in a rhombus / diamond shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249002/16314724)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This code works with both regular UTF8 characters and *surrogate pairs*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLBbhMxEL3nK0Z78kLjwHUjOFBVKoeqqIET4uB4TdYbr23ZswkI9cY/IJBypPeeuCC@KX8QxtlmW0gTS5bXs@/NvJnnWizEsC7nm41uvAsINQV4i9rwiEGJhj8ZD6QRMcJV5ZppG@HLAGj5dmq0hIgC6Vg4XUIjtGUTDNrO3n8AEWYxvwOn1f0gQoAXkK1X336uV99/0f5D@zft2/Xqx1eK32Tj0Si7Or@8ePVuko37BNoiWOIy@shTHi5dqd44ukaW06W1yPJ7/GgEuHTgRcBYgFUzUrpQIGwJ3kWdLiegueIPGa33KlApSb3HpDfBjVtSsFS7YE94bXHSTSkIO1PsOQzBnoDNe8SD1EaJMmVcVhpV9EKqCB9dAKxUL2irdo/MvVJzpmH4cq/iM2phv1pPpPxnQlasTtzJ54iq4a5F7skLZBlkef6o1n5aSU8BfS0LT6ne@DHKPy3sKDoNYx/OG@Hfustp3TX1v5eH@4lz7dmFwIoyfOqaP4I2utF4B6enuRWfBB2h9MJOKxGERBWKAl33do/QpDNGSWSn3elC5DU1QyR2YMLkgm9xa77RVg0OWnfvWlFsbTO7iV4Prjebvw)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "";//"RHOMBUS";
    int n = (int) str.codePoints().count();
    // two parts: negative and positive, i.e.
    // upper increasing and lower decreasing
    IntStream.range(1 - n, n)
            // leading whitespaces for the positive part
            .peek(i -> IntStream.range(0, i)
                    .forEach(j -> System.out.print(" ")))
            // negative part: range(0, n + i);
            // positive part: range(i, n);
            .mapToObj(i -> str.codePoints()
                    .skip(Math.max(0, i))
                    .limit(Math.min(n + i, n))
                    .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining()))
            // output the line
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output: